# Solderless header pins

Tags: connector, pin-headers

I have a device I'd like to hack. The manufacturer has provided JTAG through-hole connector in the PCB:

[image]

Due to various personal reasons I currently cannot use/access a soldering iron.

I am looking for clippable/snappable/solderless header pins similar to the ones listed on [sparkfun here](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/10527).

[image]

What are they called? I cannot find others with these terms.

EDIT: Anything that serves a similar purpose will also work. I just need a way to connect the programmer to the pins.

Answer (score 7):

Those are called **press fit** headers. Keep in mind they do deform the holes when used. Basically forcing a square into a circle

Alternative methods are using **pogo pins** with a jig of some sort. These are spring loaded pins commonly used to connect to programming points on a pcb. A jig is as easy as a small block of wood and gravity.

A haphazard option of using blue tack to hold wires/regular headers in place temporarily or hot glue as a semi permanent option. this may not be stable for some communication.

Comment: Wow - never thought of blue tack or hot glue, that's a neat way to do it in a jiffy. I would prefer something more reliable though. When you say pogo pins, do you mean something like [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4001095875130.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.258d97acobT9i8&algo_pvid=fe2ff660-40ac-4d0f-be96-3d37fa738096&algo_expid=fe2ff660-40ac-4d0f-be96-3d37fa738096-0&btsid=0b0a555f16197729789154687efdc2&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_)? After I insert it into the through hole, how do I connect it to the programmer?

Comment: Regarding press fit headers, would something like [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000790960004.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.6b3c70d4WRxgMh&algo_pvid=867cd4b9-58dc-4f14-9a28-50183a9a325a&algo_expid=867cd4b9-58dc-4f14-9a28-50183a9a325a-0&btsid=0b0a556416197734434574804ee5ae&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_) work?

Comment: There's also "conductive glue" or "conductive adhesive" - I've no experience with it so don't know if it is relevant.   --- Using pogo pins usually require that you make a fixture that holds the pogo pins and presses the pogo pins onto the contact pads on the PCB. I'm not sure pogo-pins completely removes any need for soldering because you still have to connect something to the pogo pins don't you?.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick - So the pogo pins don't stay in place if I just push them into the hole? I want to be able to push something into the hole and then connect to the in circuit programmer using [jumper cables](https://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?catId=0&initiative_id=SB_20210430024238&SearchText=jumper+cable)

Comment: @PlastyGrove Pogo pins are not designed for that sort of use.

Comment: @plasty pogo pins need some pressure. You can achieve it by gravity, clamps, screws. Google pogo pin test jig or programmer cable. The first one is fine but I'm sure it be easier if you use a header instead of individual pins. The second one is a pogo pin too not a press fit header.

Comment: @red there are plenty of pre-made pogo to cable or headers. Obviously at a premium.

Comment: @Passerby: Ah OK. I wasn't aware of those. They could be a usable option for this sort of situation then.

Comment: @red and I just saw a picture where the pins just get shoved into a typical 0.1" female header. https://blog.adafruit.com/2012/05/24/adding-pogo-pins-to-your-usbtinyisp/

Comment: @Passerby: that pic you shared is very close to what I want to do. But I'm guessing he just holds it in place with his hand, flashes the chip and then removes it?

Comment: @plasty yes or use a heavy block of wood or attach to a clip somehow https://www.instructables.com/Pogo-Pin-Programming-Connector/?amp_page=true

Comment: @Passerby - Thank you! Looks like these are called "Burning Pins" on [Aliexpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4001188020403.html). Thanks so much for your help, but I think Red's solution works best for my requirement so will be going with those. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @plasty machine translations are funny sometimes lol

Answer (score 3):

I would try a combination of

- push-fit [test-point pins](https://verotl.com/pcb-pins/test-point-pins) (test point loops)
- [mini test-hook clips](https://www.amazon.co.uk/analyzer-Grabber-Interface-Electronic-Experiment/dp/B073XBY2LS/ref=pd_lpo_328_img_1/262-4424734-1800043)

Comment: Oooh these look great. So I can insert the test point pins into the PCB and use the mini test hook clips to connect them to the ICP. This is great, thanks! Found links to these on aliexpress as well!